# Is there anyway I can edit my code and add new pages online, which sort-of operates like a blog?

Tags: web-applications, editor

Let me make this clear, I am NOT using a cms nor a blogging tool like wordpress, and I do not intend to either. With that said, is there any way I can add new pages and code online? It would just help my workflow much better without constantly uploading.

EDIT: after a bit of research I think I found some. They include Kodingen, and coderun. Is what I'm looking for considered an IDE or CGI, or am I way off?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: I have a site that is purely written in code (html, css, php, mysql). As of now, whenever I want to update my site, I have to upload the file. Example: my homepage, index.php. Whenever I want to add something, I have edit it on my code editor, and upload it online. Whenever I want to test a page, I have to constantly edit+upload it until I get it right. If there was an online code editor and filing system (so I can add new pages online) which is somehow connected to my site, I would never need to upload again, and it'd just greatly increase the workflow.

Comment: What platforms are you using (your development machine and server side as well)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm only using html, css, php, and mysql. If you're asking about my host, it's nearlyfreespeech

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess and say that you're developing on a Windows machine; your host looks like a unix shop. Get putty (or another ssh client), and use SSH to log into your server and edit the files directly using vi, emacs, or your text-based editor of choice. This way, as soon as you hit save, your changes should be visible.

Comment: Very neat... Is there a tutorial of this?

Comment: SSH is a protocol (just like the P in FTP), but designed for interactive sessions rather than transferring files. Your web host should have instructions for connecting to your server. Once you're signed in, you'll want to search the web for 'command line tutorial' and maybe 'emacs tutorial.' That should help you get your bearings. There will be a bit of a learning curve, but it's probably worth it if you plan on working websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phooji asked the correct question in his comment.

If your webhost is using a UNIX-based web server, ask your admins to enable SSH for your user account (if possible). You can then connect to your server using an SSH command-line tool (native in Linux, UNIX, OS X, third-party in Windows; I would suggest [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)) and edit your files in-place. It's a handy feature that doesn't require a third-party solution, although you will need to have knowledge of the UNIX command-line environment and text-editing tools such as vi, emacs, and nano.

If your web host is using a Windows-based server, though, you may not be in luck. Contacting your web host would be your first task, though.

Good luck. I do understand your frustration in this, as constantly uploading and downloading really sucks.